Should I apply for teaching assistance given my situation?
I'm a Master of Science Student and I'm really interested in mathematics and thinking about math problems. In my university, one of the courses for the first semester undergraduate students is mathematics, which mostly contains calculus subjects such as differentiation, integration and so on. Neither I nor the students are mathematics majors, and there is a good chance that a lot of undergraduates have problems with some mathematical concepts they learned in high school. Also, about half of the students would fail the course by the end of the semester. I know this because I was in their position years ago, and most of us didn't learn a lot from the professor's teaching, even though I studied on my own and did well.
The course usually has a TA from the university's students who is supposed to help students with supplemental problems at the end of each subject (the TA wouldn't solve all the problems for the class because there are a lot of them).
I am very good at some subjects like integration and differentiation and relatively familiar with some others. I'm very reluctant to apply for TA because I'm afraid that students wouldn't understand my teaching too or I might be bad at explaining or getting nervous and as a result I mess this up.
I should make a decision soon whether to do it or not because I should study from now to be prepared.
When I was an undergraduate, I helped two of my classmates and they got good results in the exam (probably because of me). Other than that, I have no experience teaching math to a broader audience like a class. That's why I can't make up my mind whether I should apply for it or not.

I'm not sure anyone here can answer your question. Perhaps you could meet with the local person in charge of hiring teaching assistants, explain your background, and ask for more details about the skills/experience they are looking for?

@user1149748 Thanks for the comment. There is actually no hiring and the teaching assistant doesn't get paid. I believe, one should talk to the professor and get his approval and then do some Paperworks.

Talk to the professor teaching the course and see if he/she would consider you to be qualified for the job. If you are deemed qualified, I would drop all other doubts and try (if you like it, of course). As to "the students won't understand my teaching", you forgot to put quantifiers in this sentence. That some students won't understand some of it is more or less guaranteed, no matter how hard you try, but that all students won't understand any of it is quite unlikely, given what you said about helping your friends. Whatever others have done, you can do it as well!

The only solution is: get enough preparation, like any teacher. It does not help hoping to come up with the right idees in class. Once you are well prepared, most of the students hav a cdhance to profit.
